# Extra attribute is embedded into KML file after conversion

Tags: kml, coordinates

I converted point shapefile into KML which has two columns, one is **Name of School** and second is **Coordinates**.

"Coordinates" column has only `10` rows. And in the "Name of School" column, there are `30` rows.

When I open it in Google Earth there is a coming by name column where the row has coordinates which is ok for me. The problem is about the row which has no coordinates.

There are `000` coordinates. When I click such point it is opened in between the ocean.

How can I open KML file by coordinates? In Google Earth, I want to end up only with `10` rows and not with `30`.

[image: Outcome_KML]

Comment: [@GIS Cell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/130081/gis-cell), which software/library did you use to perform the conversion? Do you have the same result when you open that KML file in any of your GIS software? P.S. I can see that you have access to QGIS and ArcGIS.

Comment: Why not to filter the source data and remove the schools without coordinates before doing the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in GIS software like QGIS or ArcGIS, then you need to filter or edit the data to remove the unwanted rows before you do the conversion to KML. Filtering (or selecting) certain rows is a basic operation that you should be able to figure out.

If, on the other hand, you're importing the shapefile into Google Earth Pro, and doing the KML conversion there, then there is no option to filter. Since it sounds like you only have 20 unwanted rows/points, you should be able to delete them manually, and then save the remaining rows as a new KML or KMZ file.